# how to push a message onto azure service bus and trigger an azure function to log it sees the message

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'm experimenting with Azure and Azure Service Bus.  I just want to push messages onto a queue and then have my C# azure function log that is sees the message.  I'm struggling to get it working.  I've created an azure account, created a resource group, created a service bus, downloaded storage explorer.  I have the shared access policy 'RootManageSharedAccessKey' which has the 'managed' option checked in the portal.

So guessing what I do next? I've gone to azure functions and created a function, shown below, in the azure portal.  When I open up storage explorer I'm not sure what option to use to connect to my azure instance with?

Any help?  Thank you!

**azure function**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static void Run(string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
}
```

Comment: You should use service bus explorer to view and send data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Service Bus Explorer you can connect to Azure Service Bus and administer messaging entities. You can download the tool [here](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases/tag/4.0.103).
[image]

Once you download the tool you run “ServiceBusExplorer.exe” In the Service Bus Explorer go to File Connect

Enter Connection string which you can find on in

**Azure portal Dashboard --> Service Bus --> Shared access policies**

[image]

After connected Successfully you will be able to see all the topics/queues in the connected servicebus select the Queue that you wanted Access

and then click on Send Messages as follows it will populate message box then you have to write the content of your message in required format(json, xml etc) and send it.
[image]

Comment: this works!  Just want to see how to get the function working now

Comment: @James great if it helpful u can mark the answer :-) or vote anyway what do u exactly want?

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse Azure Service Bus Queues with Azure Storage Queues. You can use Azure Storage Explorer to see Azure Storage Queues, but not Azure Service Bus Queues. To access Azure Service Bus Queues, [download Azure Service Bus Explorer here](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer) To my knowledge, there is no binary distribution and you're going to need to build it yourself after cloning the repo. Once you run it and connect to your Service Bus Namespace, you can create a queue and insert messages into it.

Next, you'll need to define a ServiceBusTrigger on your Azure Function. This is an attribute that will monitor the specified Service Bus Queue and poll for new messages. When it finds one, it'll call your function. Assuming you're using Azure Functions v2, [here's a Microsoft tutorial to do this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---c-example).

Comment: Okay, maybe I won't need explorer initially if I just want to create a queue and put a message onto it and then see the function log that it sees a message as I believe I can do these within the portal.  Is that correct?

Comment: There are two ways to get a message into a service bus queue. You can write a program to enqueue a message, or use a tool like Service Bus Explorer. For rapid prototyping/learning, I suggest using the tool. You cannot create a Service Bus Queue message in the Azure Portal as of now.